# Streaming data from Neo4j to Gephi - can't read url

Tags: neo4j, gephi, graphml

As it is not possible yet to transfer data from Neo4j to Gephi via .graphml- file without loss of information I tried to stream the data. Therefore the Graph Streaming Plugin for Gephi exists [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_streaming_data_to_gephi).

Following the instructions and inserting Cypher-Code:

```
match path = (:p)-[:r]->(:m)
WITH path LIMIT 1000
with collect(path) as paths
call apoc.gephi.add(null,'workspace0', paths) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

I receive:

```
Can't read url http://localhost:8080/workspace0?operation=updateGraph as 
json: http://localhost:8080/workspace0?operation=updateGraph
```

What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try changing `workspace0` to `workspace1`?

Comment: @Fabio Lamanna, yes i did - same result

Comment: Does the active Gephi window have workspace 0?

Comment: @YannisP. How can I check that? It should be default..

Comment: I made my research so in Gephi 0.9.1 the default workspace when you start the Gephi is workspace 1. So I would suggest to start Gephi, start the streaming server, uncheck SSL in the settings and in a new browser window, put in the the URL field: `http://localhost:8080/workspace1?operation=getGraph`. Provided that Gephi has loaded a graph, this request will return you a JSON with all graph info

Comment: This is what i get:

    Problem accessing /workspace1. Reason: Not Found

Comment: I was kind of having the same issue to begin with but then in the server settings I unchecked SSL and restarted Gephi and it worked for me at least

Answer (score 0):

For someone who has faced the similar issue, changing the language of **Gephi (0.92)** to English solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off ssl in the Streaming Properties.
2. Save
3. Restart Gephi
4. Load your file
5. Start the streaming server

Go to

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/workspace1?operation=getGraph"
```

All @YannisP's work.., many thanks, I just tested it and put it in an answer (so people can find it more easily).